# Convert binary strings to integer array using indexing

Tags: python, arrays

I have 4 binary data strings; I want to take the outputs as integers using the columns of each, i.e

```
p1 = '10010010101111' 
p2 = '11100011110001' 
p3 = '00001110101101' 
p4 = '00101100010010'
```

I want to take the output as integers as **[p1 p2 p3 p4]**

The following code keeps returning syntax errors. Where am I going wrong?

```
for i in range(0,len(p1),1):
    x = [p1[i],p2[i],p3[i],p4[i]]
    y = ''.join(map(str,x))
    z[i] = int(y,2)
```

Comment: You need to initialize z before you can assign values at specific indexes.  e.g. `z = [0]*len(p1)`before the loop.

Comment: yes..the only thing unforgiving was the Z...but why the '-2'??

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip() to transpose columns and the native binary string conversion to obtain the numeric values:

```
z = [ int("".join(bits),2) for bits in zip(p1,p2,p3,p4) ]
print(z) # [12, 4, 5, 8, 3, 3, 14, 4, 14, 5, 10, 10, 9, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an easier time with the following:

```
p1 = '10010010101111' 
p2 = '11100011110001' 
p3 = '00001110101101' 
p4 = '00101100010010'

p =[p1,p2,p3,p4]

y=[]
for element in p:
    y.append(bin(int(element,2)))


print(y)
```

If you want just the decimal values of the binary as integers, don't put the bin() in the for loop above.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the output appear as decimal integers?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
p1 = '10010010101111' 
p2 = '11100011110001' 
p3 = '00001110101101' 
p4 = '00101100010010'

p = [p1,p2,p3,p4]

y = [int(x,2) for x in p]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
p1 = '10010010101111' 
p2 = '11100011110001' 
p3 = '00001110101101' 
p4 = '00101100010010'
p =[p1,p2,p3,p4]
z = list(map(int, p)) # Keeps the strings in binary format
z1 = [int(i,2) for i in p] # Converts strings to decimal formatted integer
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[10010010101111, 11100011110001, 1110101101, 101100010010]
[9391, 14577, 941, 2834]
```